# Angular 2 : EXCEPTION: Error in app.component.html:1:108 caused by: too much recursion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, recursion

I have downloaded the Angular 2 quickstart and it worked fine after all of the setup.  I setup an express server and connected to that and the app continued to work fine.  I made one change to use component templateUrl rather than template property and it stopped working.  I have created a Plunker,  https://plnkr.co/edit/BSnwkRdwwHFZZs808v4m?p=preview 
to demonstrate this.  Below is the AppComponent code where I switch between properties.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
  //template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name: string;
  constructor(){
    this.name  = 'FasterLearnerII';
    console.log("App Component Called");
}}
```

The Plunk also works fine if the AppComponent uses the template property but stops working when I switch to the templateUrl.  I could find no error message with plunker but when I run in the browser the message I get is:

EXCEPTION: Error in app.component.html:1:108 caused by: too much recursion  core.umd.js:3064:13
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: too much recursion  core.umd.js:3066:17
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:  core.umd.js:3069:17
getErrorPropertiesForPrototype/<@http://localhost:3030/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:936:17

The problem is not browser specific as I have tried it in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Appreciate any thoughts on why this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put full path, 
this gonna work:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pm-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
  //template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had tried that but evidently I must not have typed it correctly.